# htaccess - js and css working for caching but not webp

Tags: apache, .htaccess, browser-cache, cache-control

All I have in my `htaccess` file is:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(js|css|webp)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "public, max-age=1928448000"
</FilesMatch>
```

when I test it in `webpagetest.org/lighthouse`, it caches the css/js files but for the webp files it returns an error: `Serve static assets with an efficient cache policy`.

Should I add something more to the `.htaccess` file?

** UPDATE **

webp:

```
accept-ranges bytes
content-length 8001
content-type image/webp
date Sun, 17 Oct 2021 11:42:03 GMT
etag "611373cb-1f41"
last-modified Wed, 11 Aug 2021 06:52:59 GMT
server nginx
X-Firefox-Spdy h2
```

css:

```
cache-control max-age=31536000, public
content-encoding gzip
content-type text/css
date Sun, 17 Oct 2021 11:42:02 GMT
etag W/"616be5d8-12b3a"
expires max-age=A31557600, public
last-modifiedSun, 17 Oct 2021 08:59:04 GMT
server nginx
vary Accept-Encoding
X-Firefox-Spdy h2
```

Comment: What are the HTTP response headers for these two requests? ie. css (or js) and webp.

Answer (score 1):

> it caches the css/js files but for the webp files

Your directives in `.htaccess` are not being processed for either CSS or WEBP files. The `Cache-Control` header in the response for the CSS file does not correspond to the header you are setting in `.htaccess`. It just so happens that this is already a future date, so it passes the "test".

> ```
> server nginx
> ```

You have a front-end proxy that is serving your static resources. It is this that is controlling your caching, not Apache. The directives in Apache/`.htaccess` are bypassed entirely for these requests.